# Delete an entity by key without fetching it first in app engine (using JDO)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

Is there a way to delete an entity without having to fetch it from the datastore first?  I am assuming I already have the key or id for the entity.
I'm thinking of something like `deleteObjectById` that would be an analogue to `getObjectById` on `PersistenceManager`.

The closest I can think of is using `Query.deletePersistentAll()` (as seen [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queriesandindexes.html#Delete_By_Query)) and specifying a query that only relies on the key, but I can't tell if that is going to fetch the entity before deleting it.

thanks

EDIT:  I know how to do this using the low level API, as well as in the python API.  I was wondering if there was a way to do it within the JDO layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datanucleus answered my question on the [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/9b6b4bca12da3315/95122ef73cfe00e9?lnk=gst):

> Not really. The issue is that an object can have relations and so,
>   since these can cause cascade of operations, it typically has to be
>   loaded into memory first. The only situation where it wouldn't need to
>   be loaded into memory was if the class of the object to be deleted had
>   no relations.
>
> Going into the low level API and blasting away objects may or may not
>   have an impact on related objects ... perhaps someone responsible for
>   it could comment on that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about JDO, but for Python this is possible with a small hack. You need to "create" a new instance with the same key and then delete it. It will hit the database only once.

```
instance = Model(key=key_to_delete, required_property='dummy')
instance.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [Low-level API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/package-summary.html)?

I think `DataService.delete(Key)` will do exactly what you need.

If you use a Long as key, you will ned to use the KeyMaker to create a key first.

```
Key k = KeyFactory.createKey(Employee.class.getSimpleName(), "Alfred.Smith@example.com");
```

Comment: I know the functionality exists in the datastore, I am trying to determine whether I can access it from within the JDO layer.